# Get product attribute value at cart page which is changed at product detailed page

Tags: php, magento

I am developing one extension.
I have created attribute at backend and assigned to product.
And I am changing that product attribute while adding to cart and I am fetching same on checkout/cart page but I am not able to get same value on checkout/cart page.

I am storing this product value in checkout/cart model like this:

```
//saving product to cart
$product_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('id'); 
        $qty = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('qty'); 
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $product->setCanImage('wasdwasdwasd');

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();
        $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Product added successfully');
```

And I can retrieve my attribute value at same page like following code but I am not able to get it on checkout/cart page.

```
$cartQuote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($cartQuote as $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
            $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
            $item->getProduct()->getCanImage();//I can get my value here
        }
```

And I have used same code which is above but I am not getting value from checkout/cart quote.

And I don't want to store this value in database because it will create trouble if many user will add this product dynamically so I think quote is good place to keep data for product.

Please suggest me solution.